# PhpStorm initiate debugging session from URL with query parameter

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

What is the correct query parameter to start a debugging session from a url?

I cannot use one of the browser extensions to turn on a debugging session as I want to start the debugging from a webhook, I just don't know the correct query to add on to the webhook url. The IDE KEY is PHPSTORM.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote -- "HTTP Debug Sessions" section -- `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name`. Obviously, if you initiate debug session from outside of IDE ... then you should either have debug panel opened .. or (better) "phone handle" icon activated.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne very much, that was just the answer I needed. I probably should have gone to the xdebug docs in the first place!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As LazyOne has put in the comments, the correct query parameter to use is XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name.